# triggeredBy a parameterizedCron in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job like this:

```groovy
  triggers {
    parameterizedCron(env.BRANCH_NAME == "master" ? "0 12 * * * % RUN_E2E=true;MODE=parallel" : "")
  }
```

Later I have conditional logic like this:

```groovy
    stage('Build Release') {
      when {
        allOf {
          branch 'master'
          not {
            triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger'
          }
        }
      }
```

The triggeredBy is not activated however. That is, "not triggered by timerTrigger" appears to be true even when the parameterizedCron runs.

I got this example from the docs [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/).

My question is, if I want my build/release stage to execute only on branch == master, and **not** during the parameterizedCron execution, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that `parameterizedCron` is *not* a `TimerTrigger`, only the regular `cron` is.

The easiest way to go about your requirement is to add a parameter and set it in `parameterizedCron`:

```
triggers {
    parameterizedCron(env.BRANCH_NAME == "master" ? "0 12 * * * % RUN_E2E=true;MODE=parallel;SHOULD_BUILD_RELEASE=no" : "")
  }
```

You can then do:

```
    stage('Build Release') {
      when {
        allOf {
          branch 'master'
          expression { SHOULD_BUILD_RELEASE == 'yes' }
        }
      }
```

Otherwise, you may programmatically discover why your build was triggered, and drop out of the build/release part if it turns out that parameterizedCron has triggered it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952773/2047614) for an example. In the case of `parameterizedCron`, the relevant part is this:

```
timerCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(org.jenkinsci.plugins.parameterizedscheduler.ParameterizedTimerTriggerCause)
if (timerCause) {
    echo "Build reason: Build was started by parameterized timer"
}
```

Finally, you may try playing around with the exact class, like this (I haven't checked it and it may or may not work):

```
    stage('Build Release') {
      when {
        allOf {
          branch 'master'
          not {
            triggeredBy 'ParameterizedTimerTriggerCause'
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your last option seems most elegant to me. Does this confirm for you that you got the right class name? https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/parameterizedscheduler/ParameterizedTimerTriggerCause.java#L7

Comment: You need to go the trial-and-error path with this last option.

Comment: `when … triggeredBy 'ParameterizedTimerTriggerCause'` works in Jenkins v2.303.3 and Parameterized Scheduler v1.0. Thank you!